# Android app hangs while submitting a comment upvote

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app

Small but mildly bothersome bug: When you submit a comment upvote, the app hangs while it waits for a response from the server.

If it takes too long to get a response, the app crashes. I'd imagine this is because there is networking on a primary thread, though I don't know the source code.

I would like to see comment upvotes submit in the background; I'm sure this isn't intentional.

Comment: Wow how did I not spot this.. thanks for reporting it, on it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in version 0.1.79 coming out around midnight UTC, thanks!